# How to hit IIS page from outside the box

Tags: iis, virtual-machine, ip-address

I'm no webadmin and new to using IIS and VM's. So i want to give a demo to some clients to show a webapp that i dev'd in IIS on a separate VM. I can already hit the pages in the IIS on my local machine using the IP address, but i'm wondering if there's a tool out there that will allow me to convert the IP address into an address like (example.com) or something

I know this is a noob question and id really appreciate it if someone can school me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can amend your local hosts file (on the host machine, not the VM), and add an entry for your vm ip address. Its located at

```
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

and the format is like this:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

It should be easy to see what to enter from the rest of the file (obviously replace 127.0.0.1 with your vm ip address)